# Woocommerce remove meta boxes

Tags: woocommerce

I want to remove some meta boxes like:

Product Short description,
Reviews

I can remove default metaboxes:

```
function remove_metaboxes() {
     remove_meta_box( 'postcustom' , 'product' , 'normal' );
     remove_meta_box( 'postexcerpt' , 'product' , 'normal' );
     remove_meta_box( 'commentsdiv' , 'product' , 'normal' );
     remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-product_tag' , 'product' , 'normal' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'remove_metaboxes' );
```

But I cant remove "postexcerpt" - Product Short description and "commentsdiv" - Reviews, because they are loaded in add_filter - add_meta_boxes

Is there any other hook after this to apply my script ? Or maybe there is another method ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function remove_my_metaboxes() {
remove_meta_box( 'categorydiv','post','normal' );       // Categories Metabox 
remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv','post','normal' );         // Categories Metabox 
remove_meta_box( 'postcustom','page','normal' );        // Custom Fields Metabox 
remove_meta_box( 'postcustom','post','normal' );        // Custom Fields Metabox 
remove_meta_box( 'commentstatusdiv','page','normal' );  // Comments Metabox 
remove_meta_box( 'commentsdiv','post','normal' );       // Comments Metabox 
remove_meta_box( 'trackbacksdiv','page','normal' );     // Talkback Metabox 
remove_meta_box( 'trackbacksdiv','post','normal' );     // Trackback Metabox
remove_meta_box( 'authordiv','page','normal' );         // Author Metabox 
remove_meta_box( 'authordiv','post','normal' );         // Author Metabox 
remove_meta_box( 'postexcerpt','post','normal' );       // Excerpt Metabox 
remove_meta_box( 'postexcerpt','page','normal' );       // Excerpt Metabox 
remove_meta_box( 'revisionsdiv','post','normal' );      // Revisions Metabox 
remove_meta_box( 'slugdiv','page','normal' );           // Slug Metabox 
remove_meta_box( 'slugdiv','post','normal' );           // Slug Metabox 
remove_meta_box( 'formatdiv','post','normal' );         // Formats Metabox 
remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv','post','normal' );      // Featured Image Metabox 
remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-post_tag','post','normal' );  // Tags Metabox
remove_meta_box( 'commentstatusdiv','post','normal' );  // Comments Status Metabox
}
add_action('admin_menu','remove_my_metaboxes');
```

just comment out "remove_meta_box" what you want to display in your page/posts.

Also we able to remove the meta boxes by changing on your custom post types name into the remove_meta_box function instead of "post" or "page".

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - it only points out generic metaboxes that have been added. You shouldn't use `admin_menu` to remove meta boxes added by WooCommerce, because they are added by `add_meta_boxes` - a hook which fires later. You should also consider using a lower priority, and correcting the `$context` parameters here, as a bunch of them are incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

WooCommerce removes the default postexcerpts and replaces it with its own version (the 'Product Short Description' meta box) (class-wc-admin-meta-boxes.php)

So like user1139767 said, you have to alter the priority. However when I tried 11, it didn't work, neither did 20. But 50 seems to do the trick:

```php
function remove_metaboxes() {
     remove_meta_box( 'postcustom' , 'product' , 'normal' );
     remove_meta_box( 'postexcerpt' , 'product' , 'normal' );
     remove_meta_box( 'commentsdiv' , 'product' , 'normal' );
     remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-product_tag' , 'product' , 'normal' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes' , 'remove_metaboxes', 50 );
```

Answer (score 2):

remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-product_tag' , 'product' , 'normal' );

isn't correct, use instead :

```
remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-product_tag','product','side' );
```

to remove the box 'keywords product'

Answer (score 0):

just added priority to add_action:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes' , 'remove_metaboxes', 11 );
```

The default priority is 10, so I added 11 to make action after 10.

Comment: Hello, do you have any ideas how to remove "woocommerce-order-downloads" postbox from order post type? Your code is not working.

Comment: yes. its remove_meta_box( 'woocommerce-order-downloads', 'shop_order', 'normal' );

Answer (score 0):

To remove WooCommerce product categories metabox, add this to `functions.php`:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes_product', 'bbloomer_remove_metaboxes_edit_product', 9999);

function bbloomer_remove_metaboxes_edit_product()
{
    // e.g. Remove WooCommerce product categories metabox
    remove_meta_box('product_catdiv', 'product', 'normal');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours on this to remove the WooCommerce short description metabox (and then add it up above the main content editor). I could ONLY get rid of the postexcerpt by using the add_meta_boxes hook. admin_menu and adminhead ran too early. So I removed everything else at the same time.

```
function WH_remove_meta_boxes() {
        remove_meta_box( 'postexcerpt', 'product', 'normal' );      
        remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-product_tag', 'product', 'side' );    
        remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-yith_shop_vendor', 'product', 'side' );   
        remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-product_tag', 'product', 'side' );
        remove_meta_box( 'wpseo_meta', 'product', 'normal');        
    
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'WH_remove_meta_boxes', 99 );
```